# show bottom on page load without any scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load the bottom of page on load without any kind of scrolling.
for example - messanger app always shows the bottom of page. there are no scrolling top to bottom on page load. I want to do that

Comment: Fix your footer to the bottom of the page: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_footer.asp

Comment: you mean ,some websites have chat option in left bottom of page fixed ,not chnageing possition on scrolling ilke..? [example](https://application.axisbank.co.in/webforms/axis-support/index.aspx) - ask Aha

Comment: Not sure whats being asked but a possible different answer may be Javascripts ScrollTo Function:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo

Comment: Please update your question to show what you have tried including any HTML and script to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: I think what he wants to achieve is something like chat messengers. when you select a chat, the last message in that chat is shown, instead of showing the first top message and then scrolling to the bottom to show the last message.

Answer (score 1):

Here set a fixed button ,that available in right bottom of page ,it is not change in scroll

```css
a{
 text-decoration: none;
}

.bar_wpp {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 70px;
  z-index: 120;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bar_wpp a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.bar_wpp .icon_wpp i {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.bar_wpp .icon_wpp {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #0c7619;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 2;
}

.bar_wpp .txt_wpp {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #0e3f14;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -o-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
    padding-right: 11px;
    padding-left: 45px!important;
    margin-left: -35px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 50px;
}


.bar_wpp a:hover{text-decoration: none !important;}
.bar_wpp a:hover .icon_wpp{background-color: #0e3f14;}
.bar_wpp a:hover .txt_wpp{background-color: #0c7619;}


@media(max-width: 475px){
  .bar_wpp{right: auto;left: 5px;bottom: 15px;}
  .bar_wpp .icon_wpp i{font-size: 25px;}
  .bar_wpp .txt_wpp{display: none;}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
page content 1<br><br><br>
      page content 2<br><br><br>
      page content 3<br><br><br>
      page content 4<br><br><br>
      page content 5<br><br><br>
      page content 7<br><br><br>  
      page content 8<br><br><br>
      page content 9<br><br><br>
      page content 10<br><br><br>
      page content 11<br><br><br>
      page content 12<br><br><br>
   page content  13<br><br><br>

<div class="bar_wpp">
  <a href="#" title="Message on WhatsApp" target="_blank">
    <div class="icon_wpp"> <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <div class="txt_wpp">
      My Button
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a fixed div to achieve what you want.

Say, you have created a `div` with class name set to `footer` as follows;

```
<div class="footer">
  <p>Anything inside the div with class footer will be fixed at bottom of the screen</p>
</div>
```

If you want this div to be fixed at the bottom of the screen, you should set a fixed position as follows in your styling(css);

```
.footer {
  position: fixed
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```